# RF Module Not Working

Tags: rf, communication, encoder, decoder

I'm working on RF Module(433MHz ) for Communication between Robot and controller. So I want to test this first.

Here is the thing 
I've used two Encoders Named HT12E and HT12D which are WORKING Fine when they are tested individually.

Now I Connected These to RF Tx and Rx, which on observation HT12E gave 1.54v(Constantly) to TX(Even while testing HT12E  gave same voltage, decoded successfully), 1.87-2v from data pin of Rx.

But I'm HT12D doesn't decode data here. This is my problem. Its so frustating for me to try for so many times and no output at all.

RF Module:: 
 http://www.engineersgarage.com/electronic-components/rf-module-transmitter-receiver

Sites Used::
http://www.technoburst.net/2011/07/rf-module-interfacing-circuit-example.html

[image] 
([Source](http://bit.kuas.edu.tw/~csshieh/teach/102A/mc/advanced/RF.gif))

Comment: How to Test RF Module alone ??
I got two pairs of RF Modules so atleast one pair must be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "voltage" you see should be the RMS of a modulated voltage, right? That's what the encoders are supposed to do.

What does the oscilloscope say about the output of the HT-12E and input to the HT-12D?

Also, if you hook the HT-12E directly to the HT-12D without the RF modules, do they work?

If you hook the TG-11A to the TG-11B directly without the encoders, do they work?

Finally, is there a particular reason you have to roll all of this from scratch? Using an existing module, be it a cheap NRF24L01 module ( http://imall.iteadstudio.com/wireless/im120606002.html ) or a robust Xbee module ( http://goo.gl/noMZ7Y ), will save a lot of time and leave the RF engineering to a team that has all of the right tools.

Comment: Thanks for reply

What does the oscilloscope say about the output of the HT-12E and input to the HT-12D?
Presently i don't have an oscilloscope

 if you hook the HT-12E directly to the HT-12D without the RF modules, do they work?
Yes they Worked

If you hook the TG-11A to the TG-11B directly without the encoders, do they work?
When i gave 5v in tx, 3.6v is recieved in rx data pin. I don't know logic behind this

 is there a particular reason you have to roll all of this from scratch?
No, i'm just doing with available things

Comment: What if you put 0V into the input to the TX -- do you get 0V out of the RX?  If so, is 3.6V enough to trigger sensing a "high" on your receiver end?

Comment: as encoder and decoder need to have 1Mohm and 33KOhm respectively to oscillator pins, but one of resistance is less in my circuit(Didn't thought that would be a problem) So by replacing this resistance value, things working fine now